# C# - Reading Sequence of Hex Bytes in Binary

Tags: c#, byte, binary-search

So I've been googling & googling for this, but I can't find a solution for my case. I could find things about byte arrays. but I hope there's also a simpler solution for my case.
Maybe it's just me using the wrong search terms, don't know.

Anyways, I already have a kinda working code which is:

```
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        // Open the file to search in
        BinaryReader br = new BinaryReader(File.OpenRead("D:/Users/Joey/Desktop/prod"));
        for (int i = 0; i <= br.BaseStream.Length; i++)
        {
            // Search the file for the given byte
            if (br.BaseStream.ReadByte() == (byte)0xC0)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Found the byte at offset " + i); //write to the console on which offset it has been found
            }
        }
    }
```

This example works. 
However, I need it to be able to search for more than just one byte. 
For example: C0035FD6

I feel like I'm missing something so simple, but I just can't seem to figure it out.

If anyone has gotten a solution for me, that would be great :D

Comment: Can you give an example? Do you need to find contiguous bytes or can they be anywhere / non-adjacent to one another?

Comment: I basically wanna search for a unique byte in the binary & then patch it. So an example of a byte that's unique in this binary: "93 0E 40 F9 53 00 00 B5 DE"

https://i.imgur.com/2RfrIP5.png (binary inside HxD)

Comment: OK so why can't you get the position where you find the starting target byte and use `ReadBytes()` to get the block? If you're doing a replace you should already know the size as well.

Comment: I just read the BinaryReader.ReadBytes() documentation (didn't know this one existed too), however I don't really understand why they use arrays in their example & I don't really understand the documentation to apply it for myself.

Comment: Will any byte of the search array be multiple times in that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this extension to search for AOB:

```
public static class StreamExtensions
{
    public static IEnumerable<long> ScanAOB(this Stream stream, params byte[] aob)
    {
        long position;
        byte[] buffer = new byte[aob.Length - 1];

        while ((position = stream.Position) < stream.Length)
        {
            if (stream.ReadByte() != aob[0]) continue;
            if (stream.Read(buffer, 0, aob.Length - 1) == 0) continue;

            if (buffer.SequenceEqual(aob.Skip(1)))
            {
                yield return position;
            }
        }
    }

    public static IEnumerable<long> ScanAOB(this Stream stream, params byte?[] aob)
    {
        long position;
        byte[] buffer = new byte[aob.Length - 1];

        while ((position = stream.Position) < stream.Length)
        {
            if (stream.ReadByte() != aob[0]) continue;
            if (stream.Read(buffer, 0, aob.Length - 1) == 0) continue;

            if (buffer.Cast<byte?>().SequenceEqual(aob.Skip(1), new AobComparer()))
            {
                yield return position;
            }
        }
    }

    private class AobComparer : IEqualityComparer<byte?>
    {
        public bool Equals(byte? x, byte? y) => x == null || y == null || x == y;
        public int GetHashCode(byte? obj) => obj?.GetHashCode() ?? 0;
    }
}
```

Example:

```
void Main()
{
    using (var stream = new MemoryStream(FakeData().ToArray()))
    {
        stream.ScanAOB(0x1, 0x2).Dump("Addresses of: 01 02");
        stream.Position = 0;
        stream.ScanAOB(0x03, 0x12).Dump("Addresses of: 03 12");
        stream.Position = 0;
        stream.ScanAOB(0x04, null, 0x06).Dump("Addresses of: 04 ?? 06");
    }
}

// Define other methods and classes here
IEnumerable<byte> FakeData()
{
    return Enumerable.Range(0, 2)
        .SelectMany(_ => Enumerable.Range(0, 255))
        .Select(x => (byte)x);
}
```

Comment: Wow! This looks great! I think it could work with this, thankyou!

Answer (score 0):

Give this a shot. You will need to verify the arrays are correct. In a binary stream, a byte array is just a collection of bytes starting at `offset` with `count` bytes as its size.

```
//here is where you initialize your array. you may need to tweak the values to match your byte range (array)
byte[] dataArray = new byte[9] { 0x93, 0x0E, 0x40, 0xF9, 0x53, 0x00, 0x00, 0xB5, 0xDE };

//here is where you initialize the NEW array you want to write where your matching array lives
byte[] newArray = new byte[9] { 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00 };

// Open the file to search in
BinaryReader br = new BinaryReader(File.OpenRead("D:/Users/Joey/Desktop/prod"));
for (int i = 0; i <= br.BaseStream.Length; i++)
{
    // Search the file for the STARTING byte of my match
    if (br.BaseStream.ReadByte() == (byte)0x93)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Found the starting byte at offset " + i); //write to the console on which offset it has been found
        byte[] tempArray = new byte[9];
        tempArray = br.ReadBytes(9);
        //now compare the arrays to see if you have a full match:
        int matched = 0;
        for (int j=0; j<tempArray.Length; j++)
        {
            if(tempArray[j] == dataArray[j])
            {
                 matched++;
            }
        }

        //if the arrays match, write your new values:
        if(matched == tempArray.Length-1)
        {
            br.BaseStream.Write(newArray, i, 9);
            break; //exit the loop when finished                    
        }                    
    }
}
```

Comment: Just tried this. 
however the offset that it gives me doesn't match the bytes I search for.
Also, the BaseStream.Write gives me this error: " System.IndexOutOfRangeException: 'Index was outside the bounds of the array.' "

Comment: Sorry for the confusion, I made some changes as I don't believe you want to only match the starting byte, correct? It could appear anywhere in the file and that would cause some corruption if it isn't a full match?

Comment: Yes, I need it to be the entire byte as match. I just tried your renewed code. It gave me offset 1302269 & that starts with the byte 22. So not sure what's going wrong xD

Comment: Tough to say as I'm not familiar with your binary or the specifics of what you're searching for in the file. I modified this line from your question to match the sequence you provided, which may explain why it isn't matching what you started with... `br.BaseStream.ReadByte() == (byte)0x93`

Comment: You were originally looking for `0xC0` but provided this example.  `93 0E 40 F9 53 00 00 B5 DE` This is why I made the comments that you'll need to modify the search terms to fit your needs.

Comment: Yea I understood, however if I did (byte)0x93, isn't it just gonna search for 0x93 instead of my entire example? I also tried: br.BaseStream.ReadByte() == dataArray[9]. But also that didn't work :p